# C++ if initializer

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(competitive_programming)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(competitive_programming main.cpp)
```

As you see, I'm using C++ 17, and I want to use **if initializer** to keep the code neat,

```
if (auto result = right.find(second); result != right.end()){
    result->second--;
}
```

But the compiler does not work as is supposed to be,

The readout seems as follows:

```
error: expected ')' before ';' token
         if (auto result = right.find(item); result == right.end()){error: expected ')' before ';' token
         if (auto result = right.find(item); result == right.end()){
```

My compiler is so, I guess:

```
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project) 8.3.0
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Have you tried: `make clean`, `cmake <CMakeLists.txt_directory>` and then `make` again?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: You might want to suggest `rm -r CMakeFiles CMakeCache.txt` after the `make clean`.

Comment: @einpoklum Isn't that supposed to be solved by re-running `cmake ..`? Perhaps not. I've found myself doing `rm -rf *` in `build` on more than one occasion :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I do that myself too. Because current cache sometimes has messed up my reconfiguring by `cmake ..`. :D

Comment: At CMake level there's various tweaks (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD and CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED, as mentioned in the one answer) but the **interesting** bit is what the actual invocation of the compiler is. After cleaning and running cmake (as Ted Lyngmo suggests), run `make VERBOSE=1` to see how g++ is being called.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: No, it isn't. CMake will re-use the cache. It's possible that just deleting the cache is sufficient but I've never checked.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

to your `CMakeLists.txt`. It makes sure that you are compiling with C++17 and it is not decayed to previous versions of compiler.

Comment: It didn't work out well. The issue persists.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz you need to add your compiler and its version to question.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz it is completely possible that strawberry perl compiler g++ is not up to date. try using another compiler.